# ng-repeat shows only the last item from json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I display a specific number of items from JSON using ng-repeat. Right now its displaying only the last item.

**JSON**

```
{  
   "list":{  
        "item": {
            "id":1,
            "img": "1.jpg",
            "user": "David Belle",
            "text": "Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes"
        },
        "item": {
            "id":2,
            "img": "2.jpg",
            "user": "Jonathan Morris",
            "text": "Nunc quis diam diamurabitur at dolor elementum, dictum turpis vel"
        },
        "item": {
            "id":3,
            "img": "3.jpg",
            "user": "Fredric Mitchell Jr",
            "text": "Phasellus a ante et est ornare accumsan at vel magnauis blandit turpis at augue ultricies"
        }
    }
}
```

**ANGULARJS**

*Controller*

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$resource', function($scope, $resource) {
    $scope.msAPI = $resource("data/messages-notifications.json");
    $scope.msResult = $scope.msAPI.get();
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <a href="" ng-repeat="w in msResult.list">
         <div class="lv-title">{{ w.user }}</div>
         <small class="lv-small">{{ w.text }}</small>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to change your JSON structure to include an array (instead of an object), as follows:

```
{  
   "list": [{
        "id":1,
        "img": "1.jpg",
        "user": "David Belle",
        "text": "Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes"
    }, {
        "id":2,
        "img": "2.jpg",
        "user": "Jonathan Morris",
        "text": "Nunc quis diam diamurabitur at dolor elementum, dictum turpis vel"
    }, {
        "id":3,
        "img": "3.jpg",
        "user": "Fredric Mitchell Jr",
        "text": "Phasellus a ante et est ornare accumsan at vel magnauis blandit turpis at augue ultricies"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're so cool. Could you please also guide me to display a specific number of items. Thank you very much

Comment: [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array, e.g. `"w in msResult.list.slice(0, 2)"`